# strange is null appear when using DB::raw in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
        AccountCostCenterUser::Where(function ($query) use ($input){
        $query->Where("account_code",'like','%'.$input.'%')
              ->orWhere("cost_center_code",'like','%'.$input.'%')
              ->orwhere(DB::raw("JSON_VALUE(account_name,'$.".App::getLocale()."') like '%".$input."%'"))
              ->orWhere(DB::raw("JSON_VALUE(cost_center_name,'$.".App::getLocale()."') like '%".$input."%'"));
    })->Where(function($query) use ($user){
        $query->where('account_user','=',$user)
              ->where('cost_center_user','=',$user);
    })->get();
```

this is my code for a query , the problem is it does return a strange sql statement and unleash an error in sql and the out put statement is like this :

```
select * from [v_account_cost_center_valid] 
where ([account_code] like %400% 
or [cost_center_code] like %400% 
or JSON_VALUE(account_name,'$.ar') like '%400%' **is null** 
or JSON_VALUE(cost_center_name,'$.ar') like '%400%' **is null**) 
and ([account_user] = 1 and [cost_center_user] = 1)
```

(why `is null` statement keep appear in the middle of my code and how solve it the problem !!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
->orwhere(DB::raw("JSON_VALUE(account_name,'$.".App::getLocale()."') like '%".$input."%'"))
```

With

```
->orWhereRaw("JSON_VALUE(account_name,'$.".App::getLocale()."') like ?", ['%'.$input.'%']))
```

You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions